# Trouble setting conditional onClick behavior

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have a Material UI table that allows sorting columns. My columns are the following:

```
const columnData = [
    { id: 'name', numeric: false, disablePadding: true, label: 'Fichier' },
    { id: 'lecture', numeric: false, disablePadding: false, label: 'Lecture' },
    { id: 'tags', numeric: true, disablePadding: false, label: 'Tags' },
    { id: 'creation_time', numeric: true, disablePadding: false, label: 'Date d\'ajout' },
    { id: 'action', numeric: false, disablePadding: false, label: 'Action' },
];
```

I want to be able to sort only on 'name' and 'creation_time'. However, the sorting method isn't the same, since the `name` is alphanumeric and the `creation_time` is a date

I already created my functions, for now they just add "function x clicked" in the console when I try each of them, but I'd like to have only both of them at the right time. Here is how I tried so far:

```
<TableSortLabel
 active={orderBy === column.id}
 direction={order}
 onClick={() => { column.id === 'name' ?
 this.createSortNameHandler(column.id) :
 column.id === 'creation_date' ?
 this.createSortDateHandler(column.id) : console.log('nope')}}
 >
```

If I didn't make some mistake, this should be the equivalence of (roughly)

```
if(column.id === 'name') {
  onClick = this.createSortNameHandler(column.id);
else if(column.id === 'creation_date') {
  onClick = this.createSortDateHandler(column.id);
} else {
console.log('nope');
}
```

So far, when I click on 'Fichier' / 'name', I get nothing, but once I click on anything else I get 'nope'.

What should I do to fix this? Thank you in advance

Comment: Does `this.createSortDateHandler` return a function?

Comment: Well technically they both console.log 'function x is clicked', so let's say yes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating the sort handlers, but not invoking them. Try this:

```
onClick={() => {
  (column.id === 'name' ? this.createSortNameHandler(column.id) :
    (column.id === 'creation_date' ? this.createSortDateHandler(column.id) :
      () => { console.log('nope') }
    )
  )()
}}
```

Or an even simpler version:

```
onClick={column.id === 'name' ?
  this.createSortNameHandler(column.id) :
  (column.id === 'creation_date' ? this.createSortDateHandler(column.id) :
    () => { console.log('nope') }
  )
}}
```

Comment: Yes they are. They are invoking the functions.

Comment: I'm not sure about that. `onClick={() => { this.createSortNameHandler(column.id) }}` is not equivalent with `onClick={this.createSortNameHandler(column.id)}`.

Comment: You're supposed *to pass a function value* NOT a function invocation to the handler... so their code is correct

Comment: for the `() =>` part, I've seen this in an other SO question, that's why I put them there. So far, with your code, it works when I click on `name`, but not if I click on `creation_date`

Comment: @AndrewLi Given the second example, `createSortNameHandler` _returns_ a function that sorts when executed, so it is passing a function.

Comment: @loganfsmyth That's right, but I'd ask the OP. I'll check.

Comment: @Jaeger As for why it doesn't work with `creation_date`... can you confirm whether `this.createSortDateHandler(column.id)` is called?

Comment: I don't know what happened, I paster @MátéSolymosi's answer, it didn't work, I tried some things and it suddenly worked... I think I made a mistake in my column's name, a typo or something. Anyway, thank you!